# Drag and drop does not work in IE 11 if page loaded locally

Tags: html, drag-and-drop, draggable, internet-explorer-11

Does anybody know why running [this](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/ASKte/4/) code snippet with jsFiddle works correctly in IE 11 but not when put together and loaded from a file stored locally on the machine? Is it because of security properties in IE 11? If so how could I change them to be able to test drag and drop using local files?

```js
function handleDragStart(e) {
    e.dataTransfer.setData("Text", "" + $(e.target).index());
}

function dragoveHandler(e) {
    if (e.preventDefault) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Necessary. Allows us to drop.
    }

    return false;
}

function handleDrop(e) {
    alert($(e.target).index());
    if (e.preventDefault) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Necessary. Stops redirect.
    }
    return false;
}
```

```css
.div123
{
     border: 2px solid #666666;
     background-color: #ccc;
     margin-top: 50px;
     width: 200px;
     cursor: move;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="columns">
          <a class="div123" href="#" draggable="true" ondragstart="handleDragStart(event)" ondrop="handleDrop(event)" ondragover="dragoveHandler(event)" onclick="return false;">Hello World</a>
          <a class="div123" href="#" draggable="true" ondragstart="handleDragStart(event)" ondrop="handleDrop(event)" ondragover="dragoveHandler(event)" onclick="return false;">HTML5 drag and drop</a>
          <a class="div123" href="#" draggable="true" ondragstart="handleDragStart(event)" ondrop="handleDrop(event)" ondragover="dragoveHandler(event)" onclick="return false;">W3 schools</a>
        </div>
```

Comment: Do you get any prompts and/or errors in the console when attempting to run it locally? If you're attempting to read from the file-system, that is usually not permitted in any browser (generally speaking) over the `file://` protocol.

Comment: You are totally right, silly me. There is a message at the bottom that the execution of Active-X elements was blocked and whether I want to accept the blocked content. Please post your comment as answer an I will upvote and accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the local file system is generally not something a browser will permit you to do over the `file://` protocol. I would expect you to see some type of prompt from the browser, or a message in the console indicating that this is the case.

If you wish to access projects locally, for testing, I would encourage you to look into [IIS Express](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/introducing-iis-express), [WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)/[MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/), or simply the [http-server module for Node.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server). They're all fairly easy to setup, and allow you to quickly serve content from any directory as though it were a live site.